# Component returning a blank screen in React: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

Tags: reactjs, json

The HeatMap component returns a blank screen, with the error occuring in the webpage console.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ClinicalRoom from '../images/ClinicalRoom.jpg'
import data3 from "../data.json"
import green from "../images/green.png"
import red from "../images/red.png"

export default function HeatMapTable({ list, colNames, room, height='auto'}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [backendData, setBackendData] = useState([{}])
   colNames = ["", "", "",""]
   
   useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/heatmapapi").then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(
      data => {
        setBackendData(data)
      }
    )
  }, [count] ) 
  list = backendData[count].mapped
  room = backendData[count].room
  console.log(list)
  return (
    <div className="theme1">
      <h1>Heat Map</h1>
      <p1 >Room: {room}</p1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>Prev</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count === 9 ? console.log("no more"): count+1)}>Next</button>
      <div className="layer"> 
        {list.length > 0 && (
          <table cellSpacing="0" style={{ height: height}}>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                {colNames.map((headerItem, index) => (
                  <th key={index}>
                    {headerItem.toUpperCase()}
                  </th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {Object.values(list).map((obj, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                {Object.values(obj).map((value, index2) => (

                  <td  key={index2}>
                    {value === 0 ? <img className="map"src={green}/> : <img className="map" src={red}/>}
                    </td>
                ))}
              </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
         )}
         <img className="room" src={ClinicalRoom}></img>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The component is being rendered in App.js like this:

```
<Route path ="/heatmap" element={< HeatMap />} />
```

The component is grabbing the data from server.js using express like this:

```
const data2 = require("../client/src/data.json")

app.get("/heatmapapi", (req, res) => {
res.json(data2)})
```

The data inside the data.json file is inside of an array and looks like this:

```
          {"room": "101",
          "mapped": 
          [{"1":0, "2":1 ,"3":0, "4":1},
          {"1":0, "2":0, "3":0, "4":0},
          {"1":0, "2":0, "3":0, "4":0},
          {"1":0, "2":1, "3":0, "4":0},
          {"1":0, "2":0, "3":0, "4":0}],
            "staffnum": 1}
```

I have no idea why but the program runs perfectly with no errors if I do the following:

1. run the program
2. set list and room to:

   list = backendData
   room = backendData.room
3. save and refresh
4. set list and room back to:

   list = backendData[count].mapped
   room = backendData[count].room
5. save and refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a representation of the initial (relevant) state of the component:
1- `backenData =  [{}]`
2- `count = 0`
3- `list = backendData[count].mapped`

From `1-` and `2-` we can deduct that the derived state `list` is `undefined`.

When you're accessing `list.length` i.e `undefined.length` it throws an error. To manage the case where `list` would be undefined, you could use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) like this: `list?.length`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
...
export default function HeatMapTable({ list, colNames, room, height='auto'}) {
  ...
  return (
      ...
      <div className="layer"> 
        {list?.length > 0 && (
           ....
        )}
    }
```